# How to implement google turn by turn driving navigation?

Tags: android, google-maps, navigation

'public class DirectionsMapFragment extends SherlockMapFragment {

```
private static final HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();

private Handler handler = new Handler();
private Random random = new Random();
private Runnable runner = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }
};

private GoogleMap googleMap;
private List<Marker> markers = new ArrayList<Marker>();

public static DirectionsMapFragment newInstance(int position,String title) {
    DirectionsMapFragment fragment = new DirectionsMapFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("position", position);
    bundle.putString("title", title);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    handler.postDelayed(runner, random.nextInt(2000));

    View view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    googleMap = getMap();
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    ViewUtils.initializeMargin(getActivity(), view);

    return view;
}

/**
 * Adds a list of markers to the map.
 */
public void addPolylineToMap(List<LatLng> latLngs) {
    PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions();
    for (LatLng latLng : latLngs) {
        options.add(latLng);
    }
    googleMap.addPolyline(options);
}   

/**
 * Clears all markers from the map.
 */
public void clearMarkers() {
    googleMap.clear();
    markers.clear();        
}

private Menu menu;
private boolean directionsFetched = false;


@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    this.menu = menu;
    //menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.directions_menu, menu);
    updateNavigationStopStart();
}


private void updateNavigationStopStart() {
    MenuItem startAnimation = this.menu.findItem(R.id.action_bar_start_animation);
    startAnimation.setVisible(!animator.isAnimating() && directionsFetched);
    MenuItem stopAnimation = this.menu.findItem(R.id.action_bar_stop_animation);
    stopAnimation.setVisible(animator.isAnimating());
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_bar_directions) {
          startActivityForResult(new Intent(getActivity(), DirectionsInputActivity.class), DirectionsInputActivity.RESULT_CODE);
      } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_bar_start_animation) {
          animator.startAnimation(true,latLngs);
          updateNavigationStopStart();
      } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_bar_stop_animation) {
          animator.stopAnimation();
          updateNavigationStopStart();
      } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_bar_toggle_style) {
          GoogleMapUtis.toggleStyle(googleMap);

      }

      return true;
}   

private List<LatLng> latLngs = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

 private class DirectionsFetcher extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Void> {


    private String origin;
    private String destination;

     public DirectionsFetcher(String origin,String destination) {
        this.origin = origin;
        this.destination = destination;
    }

     @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        clearMarkers();
        getActivity().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(Boolean.TRUE);

    }

     protected Void doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         try {
             HttpRequestFactory requestFactory = HTTP_TRANSPORT.createRequestFactory(new HttpRequestInitializer() {
                 @Override
                 public void initialize(HttpRequest request) {
                     request.setParser(new JsonObjectParser(JSON_FACTORY));
                 }
                 });

             GenericUrl url = new GenericUrl("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json");
             url.put("origin", origin);
             url.put("destination", destination);
             url.put("sensor",false);

            HttpRequest request = requestFactory.buildGetRequest(url);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = request.execute();
            DirectionsResult directionsResult = httpResponse.parseAs(DirectionsResult.class);

            String encodedPoints = directionsResult.routes.get(0).overviewPolyLine.points;
            latLngs = PolyUtil.decode(encodedPoints);
         } catch (Exception ex) {
             ex.printStackTrace();
         }
         return null;

     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
         directionsFetched=true;
         System.out.println("Adding polyline");
         addPolylineToMap(latLngs);
         System.out.println("Fix Zoom");
         GoogleMapUtis.fixZoomForLatLngs(googleMap, latLngs);
         System.out.println("Start anim");
         animator.startAnimation(false, latLngs);
         updateNavigationStopStart();
         getActivity().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(Boolean.FALSE);
     }
 }  

  public static class DirectionsResult {

    @Key("routes")
    public List<Route> routes;

  }

  public static class Route {
      @Key("overview_polyline")
      public OverviewPolyLine overviewPolyLine;

  }

  public static class OverviewPolyLine {
      @Key("points")
      public String points;

  }

  @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode==DirectionsInputActivity.RESULT_CODE) {
        String from = data.getExtras().getString("from");
        String to = data.getExtras().getString("to");
        new DirectionsFetcher(from,to).execute();
    }
}

  private Animator animator = new Animator();
  private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

  public class Animator implements Runnable {

        private static final int ANIMATE_SPEEED = 1500;
        private static final int ANIMATE_SPEEED_TURN = 1500;
        private static final int BEARING_OFFSET = 20;

        private final Interpolator interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();

        private boolean animating = false;

        private List<LatLng> latLngs = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

        int currentIndex = 0;

        float tilt = 90;
        float zoom = 15.5f;
        boolean upward=true;

        long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

        LatLng endLatLng = null; 
        LatLng beginLatLng = null;

        boolean showPolyline = false;

        private Marker trackingMarker;

        public void reset() {
            resetMarkers();
            start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            currentIndex = 0;
            endLatLng = getEndLatLng();
            beginLatLng = getBeginLatLng();

        }

        public void stopAnimation() {
            animating=false;
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(animator);

        }

        public void initialize(boolean showPolyLine) {
            reset();
            this.showPolyline = showPolyLine;

            highLightMarker(0);

            if (showPolyLine) {
                polyLine = initializePolyLine();
            }

            // We first need to put the camera in the correct position for the first run (we need 2 markers for this).....
            LatLng markerPos = latLngs.get(0);
            LatLng secondPos = latLngs.get(1);

            setInitialCameraPosition(markerPos, secondPos);

        }

        private void setInitialCameraPosition(LatLng markerPos,
                LatLng secondPos) {

            float bearing = GoogleMapUtis.bearingBetweenLatLngs(markerPos,secondPos);

            trackingMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(markerPos)
                     .title("title")
                     .snippet("snippet"));

            float mapZoom = googleMap.getCameraPosition().zoom >=16 ? googleMap.getCameraPosition().zoom : 16;

            CameraPosition cameraPosition =
                    new CameraPosition.Builder()
                            .target(markerPos)
                            .bearing(bearing + BEARING_OFFSET)
                            .tilt(90)
                            .zoom(mapZoom)
                            .build();

            googleMap.animateCamera(
                    CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition), 
                    ANIMATE_SPEEED_TURN,
                    new CancelableCallback() {

                        @Override
                        public void onFinish() {
                            System.out.println("finished camera");
                            animator.reset();
                            Handler handler = new Handler();
                            handler.post(animator); 
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancel() {
                            System.out.println("cancelling camera");                                    
                        }
                    }
            );
        }       

        private Polyline polyLine;
        private PolylineOptions rectOptions = new PolylineOptions();


        private Polyline initializePolyLine() {
            //polyLinePoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
            rectOptions.add(latLngs.get(0));
            return googleMap.addPolyline(rectOptions);
        }

        /**
         * Add the marker to the polyline.
         */
        private void updatePolyLine(LatLng latLng) {
            List<LatLng> points = polyLine.getPoints();
            points.add(latLng);
            polyLine.setPoints(points);
        }

        public void startAnimation(boolean showPolyLine,List<LatLng> latLngs) {
            if (trackingMarker!=null) {
                trackingMarker.remove();
            }
            this.animating = true;
            this.latLngs=latLngs;
            if (latLngs.size()>2) {
                initialize(showPolyLine);
            }

        }               

        public boolean isAnimating() {
            return this.animating;
        }


        @Override
        public void run() {

            long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
            double t = interpolator.getInterpolation((float)elapsed/ANIMATE_SPEEED);
            LatLng intermediatePosition = SphericalUtil.interpolate(beginLatLng, endLatLng, t);

            Double mapZoomDouble = 18.5-( Math.abs((0.5- t))*5);
            float mapZoom =  mapZoomDouble.floatValue();

            System.out.println("mapZoom = " + mapZoom);

            trackingMarker.setPosition(intermediatePosition);

            if (showPolyline) {
                updatePolyLine(intermediatePosition);
            }

            if (t< 1) {
                mHandler.postDelayed(this, 16);
            } else {

                System.out.println("Move to next marker.... current = " + currentIndex + " and size = " + latLngs.size());
                // imagine 5 elements -  0|1|2|3|4 currentindex must be smaller than 4
                if (currentIndex<latLngs.size()-2) {

                    currentIndex++;

                    endLatLng = getEndLatLng();
                    beginLatLng = getBeginLatLng();


                    start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

                    Double heading = SphericalUtil.computeHeading(beginLatLng, endLatLng);

                    highLightMarker(currentIndex);

                    CameraPosition cameraPosition =
                            new CameraPosition.Builder()
                                    .target(endLatLng)
                                    .bearing(heading.floatValue() /*+ BEARING_OFFSET*/) // .bearing(bearingL  + BEARING_OFFSET)
                                    .tilt(tilt)
                                    .zoom(googleMap.getCameraPosition().zoom)
                                    .build();

                    googleMap.animateCamera(
                            CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition), 
                            ANIMATE_SPEEED_TURN,
                            null
                    );

                    //start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                    mHandler.postDelayed(this, 16);                 

                } else {
                    currentIndex++;
                    highLightMarker(currentIndex);
                    stopAnimation();
                }

            }
        }



        private LatLng getEndLatLng() {
            return latLngs.get(currentIndex+1);
        }

        private LatLng getBeginLatLng() {
            return latLngs.get(currentIndex);
        }

    };        

    /**
     * Highlight the marker by index.
     */
    private void highLightMarker(int index) {
        if (markers.size()>=index+1) {
            highLightMarker(markers.get(index));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Highlight the marker by marker.
     */
    private void highLightMarker(Marker marker) {

        if (marker!=null) {
            marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));
            marker.showInfoWindow();
        }

    }   

    private void resetMarkers() {
        for (Marker marker : this.markers) {
            marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
        }
    }
```

}'

When i'm clicking Direction button in action bar this method calls animator.startAnimation(true,latLngs);
that time getting exception.

I have worked on google maps and route creation for the user and want to give driving direction to the user but don't know, how to create turn by turn driving direction with voice like google navigation.
google gives google maps intent but now want to use that one want to create seperate.

![When i am clicking on Directions in actionbar that time app is closing.]

```
03-23 15:32:41.701: E/AndroidRuntime(22675): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-23 15:32:41.701: E/AndroidRuntime(22675): Process: com.ecs.google.maps.v2.actionbarsherlock, PID: 22675
03-23 15:32:41.701: E/AndroidRuntime(22675): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.support.v4.view.ViewGroupCompat.getLayoutMode
03-23 15:32:41.701: E/AndroidRuntime(22675):    at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout$Bounds.include(GridLayout.java:2294)
03-23 15:32:41.701: E/AndroidRuntime(22675):    at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout$Axis.computeGroupBounds(GridLayout.java:1205)
03-23 15:32:41.701: E/AndroidRuntime(22675):    at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout$Axis.getGroupBounds(GridLayout.java:1214)
03-23 15:32:41.701: E/AndroidRuntime(22675):    at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout$Axis.createLinks(GridLayout.java:1223)
03-23 15:32:41.701: E/AndroidRuntime(22675):    at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout$Axis.getForwardLinks(GridLayout.java:1249)
03-23 15:32:41.701: E/AndroidRuntime(22675):    at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout$Axis.createArcs(GridLayout.java:1374)
03-23 15:32:41.701: E/AndroidRuntime(22675):    at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout$Axis.getArcs(GridLayout.java:1407)
03-23 15:32:41.701: E/AndroidRuntime(22675):    at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout$Axis.solve(GridLayout.java:1587)
03-23 15:32:41.701: E/AndroidRuntime(22675):    at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout$Axis.computeLocations(GridLayout.java:1694)
03-23 15:32:41.701: E/AndroidRuntime(22675):    at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout$Axis.getLocations(GridLayout.java:1718)
03-23 15:32:41.701: E/AndroidRuntime(22675):    at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout$Axis.getMeasure(GridLayout.java:1739)
03-23 15:32:41.701: E/AndroidRuntime(22675):    at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout$Axis.getMeasure(GridLayout.java:1750)
03-23 15:32:41.701: E/AndroidRuntime(22675):    at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout.onMeasure(GridLayout.java:951)
03-23 15:32:41.701: E/AndroidRuntime(22675):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16540)
03-23 15:32:41.701: E/AndroidRuntime(22675):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5137)
03-23 15:32:41.701: E/AndroidRuntime(22675):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
03-23 15:32:41.701: E/AndroidRuntime(22675):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16540)
03-23 15:32:41.701: E/AndroidRuntime(22675):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5137)
03-23 15:32:41.701: E/AndroidRuntime(22675):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
03-23 15:32:41.701: E/AndroidRuntime(22675):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16540)
03-23 15:32:41.701: E/AndroidRuntime(22675):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5137)
03-23 15:32:41.701: E/AndroidRuntime(22675):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
03-23 15:32:41.701: E/AndroidRuntime(22675):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
03-23 15:32:41.701: E/AndroidRuntime(22675):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16540)
03-23 15:32:41.701: E/AndroidRuntime(22675):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1942)
03-23 15:32:41.701: E/AndroidRuntime(22675):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1132)
03-23 15:32:41.701: E/AndroidRuntime(22675):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1321)
03-23 15:32:41.701: E/AndroidRuntime(22675):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1019)
03-23 15:32:41.701: E/AndroidRuntime(22675):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5725)
03-23 15:32:41.701: E/AndroidRuntime(22675):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
03-23 15:32:41.701: E/AndroidRuntime(22675):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
03-23 15:32:41.701: E/AndroidRuntime(22675):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
03-23 15:32:41.701: E/AndroidRuntime(22675):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
03-23 15:32:41.701: E/AndroidRuntime(22675):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-23 15:32:41.701: E/AndroidRuntime(22675):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-23 15:32:41.701: E/AndroidRuntime(22675):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-23 15:32:41.701: E/AndroidRuntime(22675):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
03-23 15:32:41.701: E/AndroidRuntime(22675):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-23 15:32:41.701: E/AndroidRuntime(22675):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-23 15:32:41.701: E/AndroidRuntime(22675):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
03-23 15:32:41.701: E/AndroidRuntime(22675):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
03-23 15:32:41.701: E/AndroidRuntime(22675):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will defiantly help you...

http://ddewaele.github.io/GoogleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock/part3

Comment: Thank you @Hardik
I have tested all tabes are working fine except direction api tab is giving exception 
03-23 15:17:04.779: E/AndroidRuntime(12532): Process: com.ecs.google.maps.v2.actionbarsherlock, PID: 12532

Comment: look like android.support.v7.widget or android android.support.v4 lib problem make sure it is latest